# How to make dotenv parse and use values from environment for Github CI build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, continuous-integration, dotenv

I use `.env` file for local development and it's not in git.

webpack loads env values from the file with this:

```
const env = dotenv.config().parsed

if (!env) {
    throw '.env file is missing in the root of the project.'
}
```

Here, if there is no `.env` file, the flow breaks and if it's local dev, then the developer knows he needs to create one from `.env.example`.

But in CI, I set env variables in yaml config in `env:` field.

However, seems like dotenv cannot easily read variables either from `.env` or from current environment.

So, can I make dotenv try to find variables both in file and environment and then throw if nothing is found?

Answer (score 0):

In one of your github actions steps, you can create `.env` file, and populate it with secrets provided by `github` and then your will have `.env` file in your project

```
- name: Create .env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo DB_SQL_LOCAL_HOST=${{ secrets.DB_SQL_LOCAL_HOST }} >> .env
          echo DB_SQL_LOCAL_PORT=${{ secrets.DB_SQL_LOCAL_PORT }} >> .env
          echo DB_SQL_NAME=${{ secrets.DB_SQL_NAME }} >> .env
          echo DB_SQL_USERNAME=${{ secrets.DO_DEPLOY_MYSQL_USERNAME }} >> .env
          echo DB_SQL_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DO_DEPLOY_MYSQL_PASSWORD }} >> .env
```